# Set array struct to session in golang

Tags: session, go

I use lib github.com/ipfans/echo-session. I can save session when set array struct

This my code:

Save session

```
type StaffInfor struct {
    Login_id         string
    Family_name_cc   string
    First_name_cc    string
    Family_name_kana string
    First_name_kana  string
    Role_id      int
    Password     string
    Message_invalid  []string
}
~~~
session := session.Default(c)
session.Set("test", listStaffInfor)// listStaffInfor is array struct StaffInfor 
session.Save()
```

Get from session

```
session := session.Default(c)
fmt.Println(session.Get("test"))
```

Console result display empty

Comment: May be your session is not stored properly? to confirm this theory Set the value and retrieve it immediately after that.

Comment: "retrieve it immediately after that" --> OK, session stored properly

Comment: "May be your session is not stored properly?" means your `session.Save()` call is not working. The library you're using internally uses gorilla session library. So it's better to check the gorilla session documentation for storing struct in session object.

Comment: As far as I test, if set string to session is working but array struct is not working.

Comment: Just added the answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Library `github.com/ipfans/echo-session` is using `github.com/gorilla/sessions` internally.

Gorilla session object is serialised using the `encoding/gob` package. So  to store a complex datatype within a session you have to register your `struct`.

```
type StaffInfor struct {
    Login_id         string
    Family_name_cc   string
    First_name_cc    string
    Family_name_kana string
    First_name_kana  string
    Role_id          int
    Password         string
    Message_invalid  []string
}

type ListStaffInfor []StaffInfor

func init() {
   gob.Register(&StaffInfor{})
   gob.Register(&ListStaffInfor{})
}
```

*Note: If you're using cookie based session, it is not advised to store large object into session, because you might hit cookie size limitation 4KB.*

Comment: Thank you!. I saw the data in the session, but I did not get it when casting. My code:listStaffInfor := session.Get("listStaffInfor").([]StaffInfor)

Comment: When type assertion fails typically you will get an error. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: THANKS A LOT, those lines were life saver... this should be markes as the correct answer.

Comment: @coung it looks like that the store keeps the actual struct under an interface thus using an pointer to the actual data values, so do a type assertion against a pointer.